# How to write helper method for PATCH request using django-tastypie?

Tags: python, django, rest, tastypie

I have a `Comment` object which has a `text` field. For editing it's text field, we can send a `PATCH` request (based on REST principles). I am using `django-tastypie` for REST API. 
Now I want to keep history of this text field, so that original text is not deleted but stored in some other object.
We can make a new `EditedComment` model that has the `old_text` and `new_text` fields.

Now my question is how do I populate this model? I will need some helper method that on every `PATCH` request, creates an instance of the `EditedComment` model and saves it in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `obj_update` method in `CommentResource`: (assuming a `uuid` field)

```
def obj_update(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        old_text = bundle.obj.text
        new_text = bundle.data['text']
        Comment.objects.filter(uuid=bundle.data['uuid']).update(text=new_text) # update comment
        c = Comment.objects.get(uuid=bundle.data['uuid'])
        EditedComment(cmt=c, old_text = old_text, new_text = new_text).save()
        return bundle
```